# How to disable tail emmission in a fork?

Tags: monero-forks, tail-emission

I've been creating a monero fork and I want to disable the tail emission but can't figure out how. Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the code. git grep FINAL_SUBSIDY_PER_MINUTE

Comment: Will that make the block reward after MONEY_SUPPLY 0?

Comment: Only once the formula makes it 0 (which it probably can if you wait long enough).